# Python PIP claims that a package is installed but whet I use package it is not found

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have been trying to setup a proper virtual environment. I came upon [this](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). But I am still unable to use the package:

```
yathi@DarkWater-U:~$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
yathi@DarkWater-U:~$ workon
workon: command not found
yathi@DarkWater-U:~$ mkvirtualenv
mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

With some googling I found that the problem is probably because I used **sudo pip install** instead of **pip install**. But now I don't know how to correct the problem and install the package correctly.

Comment: I can recommend this tutorial as the best one ever https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhevHKBy7Hc

Comment: It says: "on windows". But I am using Ubuntu here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#introduction):

```
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
...
$ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
$ mkvirtualenv env1
```